# i'm using react.js and im getting networkError

Tags: reactjs

> Error: Network Error
> at createError (createError.js:16:1)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:117:1)

Below is the code.

```
var fetchProducts = () => {
  setLoading(true);
  axios
    .get(
      "http://asia-south1-adon-interviews.cloudfunctions.net/getProductByCategory?category=kid%27s-fashion"
    )
    .then((res) => {
      setLoading(false);
      //  console.log(res)
      setProducts(res.data.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  // .finally(setLoading(false));
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Means you have a network issue. If all is okay then the issue is located at the server code (check if you are sending the correct error message)